# Allowing new users on a SQL Server database connection string

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

I am making my first simple WPF app with C# and SQL Server and I can't wrap my head around database access for new users. I am failing to understand the logic of checking if a user exists on a database and adding a new one if not.

What I have done:

1. Created a local SQL Server instance
2. Created a database and a table in it, called `USERS`

What bugs me the most is the connection string. I want to use SQL Server authentication because I will host the database publicly so I can share my work publicly and allow people to use my app if they want.

I understand I can manually create with SSMS Logins and Users and map them to a specific database, then send my users the username and password which can be used inside a connection string when they try to connect.

Which is ok for me for now; I would have anyone wanting to use the app just email me a request or something and I'll email them back the login data. But it would be better if they can register themselves.

When running locally I understand I can just put a trusted connection inside the connection string and that all works but what about a completely new user? If a new user tries to log in; what username and credentials to put inside the connection string if he does not exists, how to check him on a database if he does not have access to it?

Do I need, on a server-side with SSMS (Security-Logins and Users) create a default login and a user and only give the right to read/write to table `USERS` so it can register itself?

Am I way off?

Thank you

Comment: Desktop apps that are used publicly should not directly connect to a database. That's your problem here. It's more usual to expose web services which read/write to an internal database. Add authentication to those web services.  For an internal app, you could use AD groups and connect directly to a database.  There would be no credentials in a connection string then. This is only really suitable for small companies or prototypes though.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Its my first app and still learning. ggeorge mentioned Microsoft identity service, can you suggest any other alternatives I can read about? Thanks

Comment: The identity provider is the least of your problems here. You could consider azure active directory maybe. Depends who your users are. There are a bunch of identity providers https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/identity-providers

Comment: You could put your database in the cloud on azure. There are of course costs associated with the cloud.

Comment: Distribution to external users is one of those red flags for a desktop app. Maybe this should be a web site instead.

Comment: I am trying to avoid costs. The app is just intended for learning purposes and to be used maybe by 5 people. But I would like it to be publicly share so we can access it anytime and also to go through the experience of setting up a database online.

Comment: You could say that making an app, sharing it with and a database online is on my bucket list. Doin it in WPF because I have strong background in creating forms so I made it in two weeks time. Just not so experienced with setting everything up online.(on daily job everything id done internaly, just using AD securities and basic windows authentication)

Answer (score 0):

> I am failing to understand the logic of checking if a user exists on a database and adding a new one if not.

For this first question you should add a check in your sql `insert into` statement or create some `Unique` fields. If you wish to follow the first approach you have to do something like this:

```
//Use some parameter which supposed to be unique, i.E LastName (just for demo purposes, ofc there would be more than one person with same LastName and must be inserted into the table as valid new user)

if not exists (select 1 from USERS where USERS.LastName = @LastName)
insert into USERS(FirstName, LastName, ...)
values (@FirstName, @LastName, ...)
```

For applications like WPF, WASM that will reside in the end's user machine you should never store sensitive information (db user/pass) in the connection string. Also in most cases its bad idea even to encrypt it. Instead the most straightforward way to go is with Web API and with adding this extra layer between the UI and the database all your sensitive info will now reside to your server. In most cases you should create DB credentials for DB administrators and for end users you must use an authentication mechanism such as Microsoft Identity Platform. Its also bad idea to create a new auth mechanish from scratch, because there is a big chance to add vulnerabilities. Finally if you want to have different privileges you could assign roles (such as admin, guest etc) to your users. For more information about Identity Platform take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/

Comment: Yes, I believe I understand the literal logic and creating the syntax. It's the architecture of things that's been bugging me. So, lets say I have finished the app, tested it and my database is now published somewhere (hostgator or whatever) and I want my friend to download my app from github and be able to connect to that database. One way is that I sent him the login info which I manually created and store that login info in the connection string parameters (which is not advisable) and the other way is to use the third layer (Web api)so my fiend can create a login for himself?

Comment: In connection string you should only pass db administrator credentials not credentials for end-users. End-users should signup or login via some identity mechanism as i mentioned above.

Comment: Also your friend would be DB admin or an end-user?

Comment: So if I have some logic, an IF for my program that says I am an administrator then I would build an admin connection string and for everyone else, I should call some identity mechanism from a third party. My friend would just be an ordinary user like any other in the future; read/write across the tables that the program uses. What if I dont want any public unknown users to be able to register, I just want the users I choose. Is then acceptable just to send them login info and put that login info in the connection string when they are logging in?

Comment: Just use a connection string with your credentials and store it to the API appsettings.json and thats it. Then you have to create a signup/login mechanish with some roles if needed (guest, super user or whatever you want. There are plenty tutorials on the web) that will be used from every consumer of this api.

Comment: Yes, I already have a basic login system in place, with my credentials in the connection string. Yea so I can basically piggyback new users on my connection data. Or at least use it just at the login to check if the users exist in the USERS table. I think I know what to do now. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create some kind of user management functionality to create/read/update the users and logins. This can be a pain when using the database provider's security. Usually the app will talk to an api which will take care of the authentication/authorization part of the logic, and then the api will have a single user to connect to the database.

Connecting directly to the database from a client app is discouraged since that necessitates putting your database on the network, which is discouraged for security reasons.